# C++ Code::Blocks not compiling with header files

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Good evening! (morning?)

I was wondering if anyone is familiar with the following issues. There are three files here, which are Cat.cpp, Cat.h, and CatMain.cpp. The issues are as follows:

When I try to build Cat.cpp, I get the error "undefined reference to WinMain@16".

When I try to build CatMain.cpp, I get undefined reference errors for the speak and jump functions.

The files are in the same folder and the code is just one-liners:

Cat.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

void speak()
{
    cout << "meow" << endl;
}

void jump()
{
    cout << "meow?" << endl;
}
```

Cat.h

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

void speak();
void jump();

#endif // CAT_H
```

CatMain.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    speak();
    jump();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? Or is anyone aware of whether or not this is a Code::Blocks or a compiler issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated =)

Comment: You should check if the IDE creates a proper make file / uses right command to compile.

Comment: CatMain does not have any definition for `speak()` and `jump()`, hence undefined.

Comment: Maybe when you add header file, (File->New->File->Header file) you forgot to select "Add files files to active project Debug, Release" or something like that.

Comment: Not sure what your Cat.cpp is doing in your code but could you just add `int main() { return 0; }` to you existing code and compile again to try if it does.

Comment: Did I not link them properly? Such as #include "Cat.h" not being in the right places? Also the header file is automatically added when I make a new class, whether or not that matters.

Comment: @nullpointer Hm well I'm trying to grasp the concept of using classes and header files for use in a larger project and I followed instructions from a MOOCC video.

Comment: Ok nevermind it works now for some reason. Didn't work the first time but worked this time, but thanks for the heads up everyone!

Answer (score 0):

All that your code does as of now is something like this :

**Cat.cpp** ::

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void speak();
void jump();
void speak()
{
    cout << "meow" << endl;
}

void jump()
{
    cout << "meow?" << endl;
}
```

**CatMain.cpp** ::

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void speak();
void jump();
int main()
{
    speak();
    jump();
    return 0;
}
```

You `Cat.cpp` has a `main` method missing because of which it wouldn't compile.

Your `CatMain.cpp` does not have any definition for `speak()` and `jump()`, hence undefined error.

> Point : CatMain.cpp doesn't know what Cat.cpp is trying to work out.

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

added to Cat.cpp should let it compile.

```
void speak(){
    cout << "defined" << endl;
}

void jump(){
    cout << "defined" << endl;
}
```

added to CatMain.app should work for it as well.

Comment: Now it just outputs "defined" instead of "meow". I thought the point of header files is so that I could have the function in a different .cpp file to begin with though?

Comment: because of what I have placed in the `cout << "place something here by yourself"` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.
Most probably you don't want to compile separate files but project as whole. You should add both cpp to project in your IDE and linker will link them together resolving both issues.